# How do I fix dnf after trying to remove the system Python installation?

Tags: fedora, python, dnf

I was trying to remove python environment and I think I accidentally removed the one comes default with fedora and makes dnf command not available.

I did(not consecutively but I think those three commands are the relevant ones):

```bash
sudo rm /bin/python
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo rm /bin/python3 /bin/python3.12 /bin/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script /bin/python-argcomplete-tcsh
```

Then I found that:

```bash
n349@fedora:~/Downloads$ sudo dnf upgrade
Place your right index finger on the fingerprint reader
^C[sudo] password for n349: 
sudo: dnf: command not found
```

I tried to reinstall dnf, but it seems that dnf-4.19.0-1 is currently still installed on my machine and i cannot do it again.

```bash
~/Downloads$ dnf --version
bash: dnf: command not found...
Install package 'dnf' to provide command 'dnf'? [N/y] y


 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Loading list of packages.... Failed to install packages: dnf-4.19.0-1.fc39.noarch is already installed
```

```bash
n349@fedora:~/Downloads$ ls -l /usr/bin/dnf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 19 Mar 11 01:37 /usr/bin/dnf -> /usr/bin/dnf-4.19.0
```

I am using fedora 39 upgraded using dnf from fedora 38 preinstalled on a thinkpad x1 carbon.

```
n349@fedora:~/Downloads$ uname -a
Linux fedora 6.7.7-200.fc39.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar  1 16:53:59 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I searched online and didn't found a solution to this problem and hope someone could help me to restore the functionality of dnf.

I tried to reinstall the dependencies:

```bash
$ sudo rpm -ivh --force dnf-data-4.19.0-1.fc39.noarch.rpm \
                      dnf-automatic-4.19.0-1.fc39.noarch.rpm \
                      python3-dnf-4.19.0-1.fc39.noarch.rpm \
                      yum-4.19.0-1.fc39.noarch.rpm

sudo rpm -ivh --force dnf-4.19.0-1.fc39.noarch.rpm
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:dnf-data-4.19.0-1.fc39           ################################# [ 25%]
   2:python3-dnf-4.19.0-1.fc39        ################################# [ 50%]
   3:dnf-automatic-4.19.0-1.fc39      ################################# [ 75%]
   4:yum-4.19.0-1.fc39                ################################# [100%]
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:dnf-4.19.0-1.fc39                ################################# [100%]
```

But it still does not work and the error messages change:

```bash
n349@fedora:~/Downloads$ dnf --version
bash: /usr/bin/dnf: cannot execute: required file not found
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to reinstall the Python interpreter itself:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/39/Everything/x86_64/Packages/p/python3-3.12.2-2.fc39.x86_64.rpm \
              https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/39/Everything/x86_64/Packages/p/python3-libs-3.12.2-2.fc39.x86_64.rpm
```

For future reference, everything under `/usr` (apart from `/usr/local`) belongs to the package manager; you mustn’t delete or change files there yourself. If you want to remove Python 3, run

```
sudo dnf remove python3
```

This will tell you why you shouldn’t try this, and give you the options to add in order to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try not to break it again.

Answer (score 0):

```shellsession
$ sudo rpm --reinstall --verbose --hash https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/python3.12/3.12.2/2.fc39/x86_64/python3-3.12.2-2.fc39.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/python3.12/3.12.2/2.fc39/x86_64/python3-3.12.2-2.fc39.x86_64.rpm
Verifying... ################################# [100%]
Preparing... ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
1:python3-3.12.2-2.fc39 ################################# [ 50%]
Cleaning up / removing...
2:python3-3.12.2-2.fc39 ################################# [100%]

$ rpm --query python3
python3-3.12.2-2.fc39.x86_64

$ dnf --version
4.19.0
Installed: dnf-0:4.19.0-1.fc39.noarch at Mon 11 Mar 2024 07:38:12 AM GMT
Built : Fedora Project at Tue 20 Feb 2024 02:19:51 PM GMT
Installed: rpm-0:4.19.1.1-1.fc39.x86_64 at Wed 21 Feb 2024 07:00:46 PM GMT
Built : Fedora Project at Wed 07 Feb 2024 04:05:57 PM GMT
```

[References](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/1bbx2si/comment/kuc9iq9/?%2524deep_link=true&correlation_id=b383b908-7864-498b-8f95-c08cd0ebd315&ref=email_post_reply&ref_campaign=email_post_reply&ref_source=email&%25243p=e_as&_branch_match_id=1290834934656721091&utm_medium=Email%20Amazon%20SES&_branch_referrer=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WO62rDMAyFnyb7l0vjtEsKZQxGX0P4orSmjuXJzrK9%2FRS2%2FRxI8HF0Dkf3UlI%2Bty2jc740OqUm%2BPhoVXqp%2BkGlC4LOT4LE%2FuajDrByuNz3VKVeq%2F4qs21b85u3tIjAsld0xFpApAVjyYIHYz777IXutEEhYMwUPhBcnGH36eggUoGZVqHEZAIuQFESj9VO%2Fn3aG5WUDg4xwf5qpd4Kr1j1J0vMGHTxFME70Y0alZm6sX4eT0M9TKOpx3k61rYbrevQOHU4So5xFjMu2gdIlIu8lcLXzwGsXpL2t%2Fi%2FI9PKFv%2Fu33KtTsZRAQAA)

Comment: You’d already reinstalled `python3-dnf`, the first command wasn’t necessary. Your second command from Reddit is a subset of the command in my answer. `python3-dnf` will always fail, it’s not a command.

Comment: I examined it in an uncorrect way. Thank you anyway.